# Why does css button lose its style when clicked?

Tags: css, button, click

Im completely lost with this one. Ok so I create a button with CSS, take a look at the CSS code:

```
.UploadPhotos a:link{
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:22px;
    padding-top:2px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
    background:url(../images/btn_image.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
}
.UploadPhotos a:hover{
    background-position: 0 -24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#060;
}
.UploadPhotos a:active{
    background-position: 0 0px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
}
.UploadPhotos a:visited{
    background-position: 0 0px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Now here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="UploadPhotos">
    <a id="UpLd" href="uploader/upload.php">Upload Photos</a>
</div>
```

The problem begins when I click on it. The link is opening up another page within an iframe which is done with js. Once I click this button, all the styles for this button is gone. I get the same problem even if I set the href="#" on the link. So I don't believe its the js opening the page. I can't figure out why the style suddenly disappears once clicked on.

I added images to give you guys an idea:

Regular

[image]

Hover

[image]

After click

[image]

Highlighting text with cursor after click

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `:link` means "An unvisited link" not "Any link".

Any styles you want to apply to the links all the time (i.e. everything except the colour, background-position and text-decoration) should be applied with either:

```
.UploadPhotos a {}
```

or

```
.UploadPhotos a:link,
.UploadPhotos a:visited {}
```

Answer (score 2):

a:visited and a:active need background colors.  Once the button is clicked it's now active and visited.  If you change focus it just becomes visited.  Also, if you tab onto the control (before clicking it) you will see the same behavior because the state changes to active.

Also add another class:

```
.UploadPhotos a {
display:block;
width:100px;
height:22px;
padding-top:2px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
background:url(../images/btn_image.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: `:active` means "Being activated" (for example, in the case of a mouse user, during the time between the mouse button being depressed and it being released). `:focus` is a different state. Also, a link can be simultaneously `:link` and `:focus` and `:active`, so you don't need to explicitly set a background colour for `:focus` or `:active` unless you want them to be different to whichever of `:link` and `:visited` applies at the time (or plain a, or the browser default, etc).